# Reading an old file with newer versions of Mathematica

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting

So I was given code for mathematica software in the form of an nb-file, but my mathematica sofware isn't reading it or detecting an nb file in my computer. I'm assuming this code was done a few years ago with an older version of mathematica, is there a way I can open this with the new updated versions? I'll donate the file on here so you guys can figure out how to help with this. Also, does mathematica come with alternative language parameters? I got this code from Switzerland, so just making sure that this is not a reason as well.

Below is link to dropbox containing code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yqvnlwjj6y98gw/bifurcation.nb?dl=0

Comment: It's not detecting it at all, so no error is displayed.

Comment: I can't see it in the folder where I placed it in.  Not detecting it at all

Comment: No, I mean that when I try to open the file from mathematica that I can't see the file when I choose the folder to download from. Perhaps it could be my software, I'm essentially streaming mathematica through the school's open source web receiver

Comment: I have v12.2.0 running on Win7-x64. The file bifurcation.nb runs (there are many messages). It creates a deep folder structure (HY-DATA) on the C-drive and puts a picture in there.

Comment: @Syed, how did you open the file? I'm new to mathematica so not sure if I'm doing this right

Comment: But was the file pre-allocated to open with Mathematica? That's what I'm having trouble with, my computer can't find a program to open the file

Comment: @Moo I'm using mathemtica through my schools citrix receiver, it's like streaming software through our school website. So I don't have the actual software in my computer so I don't think the software can detect it through the usual ways like a matlab file

Comment: I downloaded to C: drive and double clicked. What is your local OS? What is the OS that citrix is presenting to you? Can you download your file to your university account (drive space `/home/user/...`) and open from there? Citrix server may not be willing to open files from your local desktop due to some restriction. On windows, if the file is not registered (there is something wrong with the installation most likely but even) then you can right-click and click `Open with` and choose the app.

Comment: That worked!!! I put it in the C: drive and it was able to take it. Thank you!!